# Why does my hdd copy files when I intend to move them? Using Gnome Files GUI

Tags: files, hard-disk

I have an extra HDD that I am trying to move files from to my main ssd and when I drag the files from one window to the other it copies them over, rather than moving them. Why is this? How can I get it to properly move files rather than copy them over?

Comment: You are using different partitions: [How does Linux's mv work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28998036/13594705)

Comment: If you're using the GUi, IIRC you need to press Ctrl (or Shift, or Alt, can't remember which of those does what) while dragging to move across partitions instead of copying. The icon under the pointer will change when you press the button, so you can tell which action is going to be taken.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The default action is move inside the filesystem and copy to another filesystem